# Church lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I had to implement the haskell map function to work with church lists which are defined as following:

```
type Churchlist t u = (t->u->u)->u->u
```

In lambda calculus, lists are encoded as following:

```
[] := λc. λn. n
[1,2,3] := λc. λn. c 1 (c 2 (c 3 n))
```

The sample solution of this exercise is:

```
mapChurch :: (t->s) -> (Churchlist t u) -> (Churchlist s u)
mapChurch f l = \c n -> l (c.f) n
```

I have NO idea how this solution works and I don't know how to create such a function. I have already experience with lambda calculus and church numerals, but this exercise has been a big headache for me and I have to be able to understand and solve such problems for my exam next week. Could someone please give me a good source where I could learn to solve such problems or give me a little guidance on how it works?

Comment: The [Church encoding](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Church_encoding#List_encodings) page on wikipedia seems like a good place to start from.

Comment: @jcdmb: Do you study computer science at KIT?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

All lambda calculus data structures are, well, functions, because that's all there is in the lambda calculus. That means that the representation for a boolean, tuple, list, number, or anything, has to be some function that represents the active behavior of that thing.

For lists, it is a "fold". Immutable singly-linked lists are usually defined `List a = Cons a (List a) | Nil`, meaning the only ways you can construct a list is either `Nil` or `Cons anElement anotherList`. If you write it out in lisp-style, where `c` is `Cons` and `n` is `Nil`, then the list `[1,2,3]` looks like this:

```
(c 1 (c 2 (c 3 n)))
```

When you perform a fold over a list, you simply provide your own "`Cons`" and "`Nil`" to replace the list ones. In Haskell, the library function for this is `foldr`

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Look familiar? Take out the `[a]` and you have the exact same type as `Churchlist a b`. Like I said, church encoding represents lists as their folding function.

---

So the example defines `map`. Notice how `l` is used as a function: it is the function that folds over some list, after all. `\c n -> l (c.f) n` basically says "replace every `c` with `c . f` and every `n` with `n`".

```
(c 1 (c 2 (c 3 n)))
-- replace `c` with `(c . f)`, and `n` with `n`
((c . f) 1 ((c . f) 2) ((c . f) 3 n)))
-- simplify `(foo . bar) baz` to `foo (bar baz)`
(c (f 1) (c (f 2) (c (f 3) n))
```

It should be apparent now that this is indeed a mapping function, because it looks just like the original, except `1` turned into `(f 1)`, `2` to `(f 2)`, and `3` to `(f 3)`.

Comment: This explanation is just DIVINE! Thanks a lot. You have saved my day XD

Answer (score 7):

So let's start by encoding the two list constructors, using your example as reference:

```
[] := λc. λn. n
[1,2,3] := λc. λn. c 1 (c 2 (c 3 n))
```

`[]` is the end of list constructor, and we can lift that straight from the example.  `[]` already has meaning in haskell, so let's call ours `nil`:

```
nil = \c n -> n
```

The other constructor we need takes an element and an existing list, and creates a new list.  Canonically, this is called `cons`, with the definition:

```
cons x xs = \c n -> c x (xs c n)
```

We can check that this is consistent with the example above, since

```
cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil))) =
cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (\c n -> n)) = 
cons 1 (cons 2 (\c n -> c 3 ((\c' n' -> n') c n))) =
cons 1 (cons 2 (\c n -> c 3 n)) =
cons 1 (\c n -> c 2 ((\c' n' -> c' 3 n') c n) ) =
cons 1 (\c n -> c 2 (c 3 n)) =
\c n -> c 1 ((\c' n' -> c' 2 (c' 3 n')) c n) =
\c n -> c 1 (c 2 (c 3 n)) =
```

Now, consider the purpose of the map function - it is to apply the given function to each element of the list.  So let's see how that works for each of the constructors.

`nil` has no elements, so `mapChurch f nil` should just be `nil`:

```
mapChurch f nil
= \c n -> nil (c.f) n
= \c n -> (\c' n' -> n') (c.f) n
= \c n -> n
= nil
```

`cons` has an element and a rest of list, so, in order for `mapChurch f` to work propery, it must apply `f` to the element and `mapChurch f` to rest of the list.  That is, `mapChurch f (cons x xs)` should be the same as `cons (f x) (mapChurch f xs)`.

```
mapChurch f (cons x xs)
= \c n -> (cons x xs) (c.f) n
= \c n -> (\c' n' -> c' x (xs c' n')) (c.f) n
= \c n -> (c.f) x (xs (c.f) n)
-- (c.f) x = c (f x) by definition of (.)
= \c n -> c (f x) (xs (c.f) n)
= \c n -> c (f x) ((\c' n' -> xs (c'.f) n') c n)
= \c n -> c (f x) ((mapChurch f xs) c n)
= cons (f x) (mapChurch f xs)
```

So since all lists are made from those two constructors, and `mapChurch` works on both of them as expected, `mapChurch` must work as expected on all lists.

Answer (score 3):

Well, we can comment the Churchlist type this way to clarify it:

```
-- Tell me...
type Churchlist t u = (t -> u -> u) -- ...how to handle a pair
                    -> u            -- ...and how to handle an empty list
                    -> u            -- ...and then I'll transform a list into 
                                    -- the type you want
```

Note that this is intimately related to the `foldr` function:

```
foldr :: (t -> u -> u) -> u -> [t] -> u
foldr k z [] = z
foldr k z (x:xs) = k x (foldr k z xs)
```

`foldr` is a very general function that can implement all sorts of other list functions.  A trivial example that will help you is implementing a list copy with `foldr`:

```
copyList :: [t] -> [t]
copyList xs = foldr (:) [] xs
```

Using the commented type above, `foldr (:) []` means this: "if you see an empty list return the empty list, and if you see a pair return `head:tailResult`."

Using `Churchlist`, you can easily write the counterpart this way:

```
-- Note that the definitions of nil and cons mirror the two foldr equations!
nil :: Churchlist t u
nil = \k z -> z

cons :: t -> Churchlist t u -> Churchlist t u
cons x xs = \k z -> k x (xs k z)  

copyChurchlist :: ChurchList t u -> Churchlist t u
copyChurchlist xs = xs cons nil
```

Now, to implement `map`, you just need to replace `cons` with a suitable function, like this:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f xs = foldr (\x xs' -> f x:xs') [] xs
```

Mapping is like copying a list, except that instead of just copying the elements verbatim you apply `f` to each of them.

Study all of this carefully, and you should be able to write `mapChurchlist :: (t -> t') -> Churchlist t u -> Churchlist t' u` on your own.

Extra exercise (easy): write these list functions in terms of `foldr`, and write counterparts for `Churchlist`:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
append :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]

-- Return first element of list that satisfies predicate, or Nothing
find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
```

If you're feeling like tackling something harder, try writing `tail` for `Churchlist`.  (Start by writing `tail` for `[a]` using `foldr`.)